# Vue El-Select doesn't work as expected while passing value from parent to child using watch

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

Component A

```
  <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select Action" @change="updateDropdowns($event)" prop="action">
     <el-option
        v-for="item in options"
        :key="item.value"
        :label="item.label"
        :value="item.value"
     >
   </el-option>
</el-select>

<tableview 
    :action="this.value"
    v-show="false">
</tableview>

<script> 
  export default {
     name: 'warehouseAdd',
     components: {
       tableview
     },
     props: [
      'component'
  ],
  

  data() {
   return {
    options: [
    {
      value: 'add',
      label: 'Add'
    }, {
      value: 'edit',
      label: 'Edit'
    }
  ],
  value: '',
```

Component B

```
<script>
   props: [
     'action'
   ],
   watch: {
     'action': function (value) {
         console.log(value); 
         //Select value from dropdown doesn't pass the value at 1st attempt.
         //If I again select the value from dropdown then I get the value.
      }
   }
```

Here whenever I try to get value.. I am unable to get value on first event. I need value once I select value from dropdown. I might be doing something wrong not exactly sure.. new to VueJs.

Please let me know how do I pass value at 1st instance to Component B.

Although I am getting the value in Component A on first attempt just not getting at Component B

I am able to fetch dropdown value in parent component but unable to fetch the same in child component when I initially select the value for 1st time. When I change the value of dropdown 2nd time then I get the value in child component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question title you said that `El-Select doesn't work as expected`. Actually it works as **expected**. When you **reload** the page, all Vue data come back to their initial values. So when you set `value: ''` in **component A** (that I called it `parentTable` in my following codes), then after reloading the page the value of `''` comes back to that `value` data. If you want to store the value of selected item **before** reloading page, there are some solutions to that. One of them is using [Window localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp). Here is the codes that works for me:

> parentTable.vue component:

```html
<template>
<div>
  <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select Action">
    <el-option
        v-for="item in options"
        :key="item.value"
        :label="item.label"
        :value="item.value"
    >
    </el-option>
  </el-select>

  <tableview
      :action="this.value"
      v-show="false">
  </tableview>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import tableview from "./tableview";
export default {
  name: "parentTable",
  components: {
    tableview
  },


  data() {
    return {
      options: [
        {
          value: 'add',
          label: 'Add'
        }, {
          value: 'edit',
          label: 'Edit'
        }
      ],
      value: null,
    }
  },

  watch: {
    value: function (newVal) {
      this.getValueOf(newVal);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getValueOf: function (storeValue) {
      localStorage.setItem("option", storeValue);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    /* Here we get the previous selected item from localStorage */
    this.value = localStorage.getItem("option");
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> tableview.vue component:

```html
<template>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "tableview",
  props: [
    'action'
  ],
  watch: {
    action: function (value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: My bad! Actually I should have mentioned it properly. I have updated the question. Can you please check.

Comment: Did you tried my answer? If you have problem with that please mention the problem.

Comment: Yes I tried. Still unable to fetch value in child component in first attempt. When I re-select the options then in 2nd attempt I get the value in child component. I actually don't need previous data so Local storage will be of no use. To achieve this I added value inside watch in parent component. But didn't work as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ```first attempt```? At first you yourself defined the ```value: ''```  in parent component. So the value is an empty string!

Comment: Please check this video. Then I think you can understand better  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DXl7HzWCVaFVa4_Gyn7a9E9PxAfpEKBl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code I posted works fine in my development environment, what you see in your project may be affected by other data or methods in your site. I suggest to disable the functionality of other parts (for example comment them temporary) to find out which part cause the problem. You can simply copy and paste the two component I posted in answer in two new and blank Vue components to see that works as expected. Also I saw an error in the console in the video but the message of it was not clear!